# Where is this error message coming from? Simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, simple-form

i'm getting this error message popping up with strange styling. Where in my application is it coming from? I'm using the simple form gem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is from HTML 5 form validation. You can disable this easily adding this options on your simple_form initializer:

```
SimpleForm.disable_browser_validations = true  # default is false
```

Or you can disable all HTML 5 stuff with:

```
SimpleForm.use_html5 = false  # default is true
```

See more info about this on simple_form [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.rdoc).

These options don't work with simple_form 1.3.1, only with simple_form master or newer versions.

Comment: Cool, thanks. How would you customize the content of the error messages coming from this html 5 form validation?

Comment: I think that has no way to do this.

Comment: are you using the simple_form master?

Comment: I don't know. I put this in my gem file: `gem "simple_form"`

Comment: To use simple_form master please change this line to: `gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'`

Comment: You can also disable on a per-form basis, by including this in the form declaration: `simple_form_for(@my_model, url: my_model_path, html: {novalidate: true}) do |f|`